# Передача данных из диалога в главное окно

Tags: c++, qt

Здравствуйте!

Пишу код в Qt Creator.

5 часов мучаюсь с вопросом:

Как же передать данные из диалога в главное окно (MainWindow) по нажатию кнопки?
Перечитал кучу материала и все никак не могу понять.

Задача:
При нажатии на кнопку start_btn открывается диалог. В нем форма. При нажатии на кнопку ОК - данные передаются в MainWindow и диалог закрывается.

Вот код mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
 ui->setupUi(this);
 ui->label->hide();
 connect(ui->start_btn,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(open_createdialog()));
 CreateDialog *d;
 connect(d,SIGNAL(sendData(QString,QString)),this,SLOT(set_data(QString,QString)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
 delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::open_createdialog()
{
 CreateDialog d;
 d.exec();
}

void MainWindow::set_data(QString name, QString Yname)
{
 qDebug() << name;
}
```

Это код createdialog.cpp

```
    CreateDialog::CreateDialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::CreateDialog)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  connect(ui->ok_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onSendData()));
}

CreateDialog::~CreateDialog()
{
  delete ui;
}

void CreateDialog::onSendData()
{
  emit sendData( ui->lineEdit->text(), ui->lineEdit_2->text() );
}
```

При запуске пишет: Программа неожиданно завершилась.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Сделал коннект в функции создания окна и передал ссылку на объект через &.

Привожу код:

```
void MainWindow::open_createdialog()
{
 CreateDialog d;
 connect(&d,SIGNAL(sendData(QString,QString)),this,SLOT(set_data(QString,QString)));
 d.exec();
}
```